# Helping others in the darkness

Tags: practical-islam, helping

Salaam,

I have a small issue with the niyat i made a long time ago. Last year i put some outdoor lights in my neighbour to help my community to cross the path at night as it is the shared path by 7 houses. It was so dark that kids cried at night with their parents when they passed through that path. However each house as their own outdoor light which they dont want to turn on. Therefore, my wife asked me to put 5 lights in that path so everyone will feel ok crossing this path and ask me to do niyat as "We are doing it to for good cause and Allah will be happy from us to show light in the darkness". Now i want to take one off from it and want to use it for my home. Can i use it in my house or i shouldnt use it in my house because of niyat? She said you cant use it as I have done niyat in the past. Please help with your knowledge.

Comment: If I were to make an intention to `Read Quran Daily` however, lets say I don't. Allah knew I made an intention, and not a promise.

Answer (score -1):

im very intrested about ur question.im decided to answer ur question right on..haha..
u see in Islam,we have a very beautiful connection between ourself and others..Islam focus on treating kind deeds not only toward ourself,our siblings in Islam and non muslim too.

u can rather use the light for ur house.and try to ask directly to ur neighbors.ask them directly about ur good deeds.so its clear negative thought between u and ur neighboor.its make u more confident toward ur action itself.

i will give a hadith about your problem.hope can ease u to be more confident in the future.

From Abu Hurairah Radiallahu Anhu, from Rasulullah Sallallahu Alaihi Wassallam he said: Whoever believes in Allah and the hereafter then he should glorify his neighbor.

---

the below section i copy from internet.tq

Islam is a religion that is very concerned about brotherhood and always encourages its people to always live together to avoid disputes or divisions in family life, neighbors, society and the country. Know, that we live in this world need each other and can not live alone, because that is why our religion encourages its people to always maintain good relations with fellow human beings whether siblings, friends or neighbors.

Imam Nawawi Rahmatullah Ta'ala has stated that the people who can be considered as neighbors are people who live close to our house, people who live within a distance of forty houses from our house in all directions or corners either from the north, east , south and west.

Rasulullah Sallallahu Alaihi Wassallam reminded that having a good neighbor is one of the signs of goodness and happiness. In a hadith narrated by Ibn Hibban, from Saad bin Abi Waqas, Rasulullah Sallallahu Alaihi Wassallam:

The four things that are a sign of happiness are pious women, spacious living and good neighbors as well as owning a comfortable vehicle.